# How to check the amount of packets in a receive buffer of a raw socket

Tags: python, linux, sockets, networking

I have written a linux server receiving packets on a specific Ethernet-type (using a raw socket), and sending them on a different ethernet device. The thing is, the rate I need to receive the packets, is greater then the rate I can send them to the other interface. So I'm using the socket buffer, untill it gets full, and then I expect packets drop.
I have set the buffer size using

```
setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, RECVBUF, 20 * 1024 * 1024)
```

And validating using getsockopt, I do see the socket was configured correctly.

The thing is I start do drop packets much faster then I expected (nearly 10 times)
What I want to do, is get the amount of packets in the socket buffer, that I will be able to print the time left untill it is full.

(The server is written in Python, yet I would be able to "translate" from other languages)

Comment: Is this a raw socket or a UDP one? If you're talking about TCP then the very idea of packets is largely irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, it is a raw socket

Comment: If it's raw then you're responsible for parsing out the data and dealing with any framing issues that arise. It's probably better to make your code more performant, or perhaps rewrite all or part of it in a language that can keep up with the data rate. Is this a raw socket as in `SO_RAW` or as in a packet capture source like `libpcap`?

Comment: As an SO_RAW. The problem is the device I want to write to is slow, so writing a faster software won't help.I don't have framing issues.

Comment: You should probably avoid the buffer and receive packets independently. Buffering is intended for stream-type sockets, not raw ones. If you're having a drop problem related to your output device being flooded then buffering isn't going to fix the problem. Why not pull these from the input device and throw them into a local array you can pop from to feed into the other device?